# Sticky Footer with Gradient Background

Tags: html, css, gradient, sticky-footer

Currently having some issues with a sticky footer and body having a gradient background. The content within my wrapper overflows into the footer.

All help is appreciated:

CSS

```
html {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000 0%,#ffffff 100%); 
    background-attachment:fixed;
    color:red;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
}

footer {
    background:#CCC;
    margin-top:-50px;
    width:100%;height:50px;
}
```

and http://jsfiddle.net/ZqkY7/14/

Comment: Do you really need `margin-top:-50px;` on the footer?

Comment: Without even testing your CSS, I can see potential issues. I posted an answer that will solve your sticky footer issues by assigning it a z-index higher than everything else, as well as making it "sticky".

Comment: Yup, without the margin-top:-50px; then the footer would be "below" the wrapper which is 100% height so even if the content didn't fill the page up you would still have to scroll down to view the content.

Comment: sticky footer: http://jsfiddle.net/ZqkY7/15/ `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` added to `.footer` class

Comment: There's been a bit of a mixup of what I want. That's a fixed footer, I want a sticky footer that remains at the bottom no matter how much content is on the page. Fixed makes the footer display on the screen at all times. I've solved the problem (I think) and will post the solution.

Comment: I don't see the difference between fixed and "sticky" except one is embedded next to the body, and the other is above and over it. The small gap of 50px lost using fixed is the same when you do with a "sticky" element. Also, you can always account for your body with height: calc(100% - 50px) and then do it like that as well.

Comment: Fixed = The footer is always on the screen, you scroll up, you scroll down. The footer remains on the screen at all times.

Sticky = The footer is ALWAYS at the "bottom" of the body. So if the content doesn't fill up the whole window the footer is still at the bottom of the page. If content goes over the fold the footer "follows" it.

I like your calc solution tho. Might do some fiddling.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a z-index that is higher than the page by using:

```
z-index: 1000;
```

And you can even just position it using fixed like:

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;  
}
```

Bam! Sticky footer.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZqkY7/15/

Comment: was about to answer with the fixed footer suggestion you posted. here's a fiddle with it working if you want to include: http://jsfiddle.net/ZqkY7/15/

Comment: Thanks, I'll add it to my post!

Answer (score 0):

best to give your wrapper some padding to account for the footer

```
#wrapper {
  min-height:100%;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a sticky footer as @Teknikitsune suggests, which I think is what you're after. In order to solve the content displaying under the footer you just need to add a margin bigger than your footer to the wrapper panel:

```
#wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    margin-bottom:55px; <!-- added to stop text disappearing under footer -->
}

footer {
    position: fixed;   <!-- for sticky footer -->
    bottom: 0px;       <!-- for sticky footer -->
    background:#CCC;
    width:100%;height:50px;
}
```

I also removed the `margin-top:-50px;` from your `footer` class which isn't required.

### [Sample JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqkY7/18/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution, will hopefully be useful for others.

```
html {
    height:100%;
}

body {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000 0%,#ffffff 100%); 
    background-attachment:fixed;
    color:red;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    height:100%;height:auto !important;min-height:100%;
}

.wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1024px;
}

footer, .push {
    height:50px;
}

footer {
    background:#CCC;
    margin-top:-50px;
    min-width:1024px;
}
```

with content:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZqkY7/19/

without content:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZqkY7/21/